# Pass cursor name from a variable

Tags: oracle

I have a package that contains a procedure(takes an input parameter;cursor name) and two cursors.
The procedure is to use the cursor specified by the input parameter

```
  PROCEDURE insertdetails(typ IN VARCHAR2) IS  
  BEGIN
    OPEN typ;
    LOOP
      FETCH typ INTO colA;
      EXIT WHEN typ%notfound;
      --MISSING CODE
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

if i run the procedure and pass on of the name of the cusrsor as an input parameter i get the  error PLS-00456: item 'TYP' is not a cursor
Is their a way out of this

Comment: I don't think you can do this. You could pass in a sql statement which you could execute if that helps? Can you provide any details of the cursor you are passing in / what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Both cursors pick same number of records from the same tables but the conditions for each are different. The records will then be inserted by the procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use REF CURSORS to do this.  [Here's a pretty good explanation](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php).

Your procedure definition would look like this:

```
PROCEDURE insertdetails(typ IN sys_refcursor) IS
```

You would probably not open the cursor in this procedure, generally you open it elsewhere, in the code where the cursor is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cursors are declared elsewhere in the package, you could use the parameter to decide which actual cursor to work with, something like:

```
PROCEDURE insertdetails(typ IN VARCHAR2) IS  
BEGIN
  IF typ = 'CURSOR_A' THEN
    OPEN cursor_a;
    LOOP
      FETCH cursor_a INTO colA;
      EXIT WHEN cursor_a%notfound;
      --MISSING CODE
    END LOOP;
  ELSE
    OPEN cursor_b;
    LOOP
      FETCH cursor_b INTO colA;
      EXIT WHEN cursor_b%notfound;
      --MISSING CODE
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
END;
```

Or if the missing code is common, as seems likely:

```
PROCEDURE insertdetails(typ IN VARCHAR2) IS  
BEGIN
  IF typ = 'CURSOR_A' THEN
    OPEN cursor_a;
  ELSE
    OPEN cursor_b;
  END IF;

  LOOP
    IF typ = 'CURSOR_A' THEN
      FETCH cursor_a INTO colA;
      EXIT WHEN cursor_a%notfound;
   ELSE
      FETCH cursor_b INTO colA;
      EXIT WHEN cursor_b%notfound;
   END IF;
    --MISSING CODE
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Either way you might prefer a `case` over an `if`; particularly if the number of possible cursors that `typ` can represent grows.